# Deleting records that are not joined on in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 database. This database has two related tables: Customer and Order. My tables look like this:

```
Customer
--------
ID
FirstName
LastName

Order
-----
ID
CustomerID
Amount
ShipDate
```

I need to delete all customers that do NOT have any orders. I cannot figure out the best way to do this. Can someone tell me how to do this? the NOT part is what keeps getting me. Originally I was using "IN" but it's stumping me.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using the IN operator, use a subquery and `NOT` [`EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx), something like:

```
DELETE Customers
FROM   Customers c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Orders o
    WHERE o.CustomerID = c.ID
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE Customer 
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT Customer.ID
    FROM Customer 
    LEFT JOIN Order ON
        Customer.ID = ORder.CustomerID
    WHERE ORder.CustomerID IS NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete from Customer 
WHERE ID in 
(
   SELECT C.ID
     FROM Customer C
   Left Outer Join Order O ON C.ID = O.CustomerId
   WHERE O.ID IS NULL
)
```